# pip install + get the errors about Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None))

Tags: linux, rhel, yum, pip

we are trying to install the following Jinja ( on redhat machine version 7.2 )

```
pip install  Jinja2-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Processing ./Jinja2-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from Jinja2==2.10)
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution'))': /simple/markupsafe/
```

but not understand why we get the message about

```
 Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution'))': /simple/markupsafe/
```

what could be the problem here ?

Comment: The error `Temporary failure in name resolution` would normally indicate a DNS failure.  Is DNS working properly on this system?  Do you have a custom Python package server configured?

Comment: yes DNS is ok , already checked the /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: Can you run `pip instal -vvv Jinja2-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl` and add the output to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Running with `pip install -vvv` pointed me to the right solution :
 
I have SSLKEYLOGFILE pointing to a location in a VeraCrypt driver.
 
Debug results gave me the following pointer:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Q:\\WireShark\\ssl.log'
```

... solution? 
Mounted the VeraCrypt driver on Q: and the problem was gone ...